# Fetch All users who has at least one post in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Please guide me,

How can I get all users in Laravel, who has posted at least single post. And skip who has not posted any posts.

I am trying this. But it is getting All users.

```
$users = User::with('post')->get();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `has()` method for Eloquent models -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

```
$users = User::with('post')->has('post')->get();
```

You can take users with active posts using `whereHas()`. Remember it. :)

```
$users = User::with('post')->whereHas('post', function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_active', '=', true);
})->get();
```

Comment: I recommend to you watch some LaraCasts. It really helps with eloquent relations. :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will definitely watch LaraCasts videos.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
User::with('post')->has('post')->get();
```

or `whereHas` (from [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships))

```
// Retrieve all posts with at least one comment containing words like foo%
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$users = User::has('post')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for extra info:

If we want to fetch users who have written at least 5 posts, we'd do it like this:

```
$users = User::has('post', '>=', 5)->get();

// same with whereHas
$user = User::whereHas('post', $callback, '>=', 5);
```